# jQuery validation simplification

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to use error messaging but not have to write out messaging for each form, there are over 20 on this site. The forms all have this structure:

```
   <li>
        <label for="firstName">First Name*</label>
        <input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text">
    </li>

    <li>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name*</label>
        <input name="lastName" id="lastName" type="text">
    </li>
```

I have the following validation rules:

```
$.validator.messages.required = function (param, input) {
    msg = $("input").prev("label").eq(0).text();
    return 'Please fill out the ' + msg + ' required field.';
 }
```

This inserts the text from the first error field's label for each error. Previous to this it created a string with every error field's label for each error "Please fill out the First Name, Last Name, (etc) required field.'

How do I get the previous label for each error class and use that text? I can't get .each() to work here. Thanks.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2cL6u7j/).

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle ?

Comment: yes, I added the link to the original question

Comment: You should **NOT** have your `.validate()` method contained within a `click` handler!  It belongs within the DOM ready event handler because it's only used for initialization.

Comment: The form is brought in via ajax, has to use a click handler.

Comment: I could understand that if the click handler was for the button that brings in the form.  However, your click handler is for the submit button of the form itself!  Makes no sense.

Comment: Change the selector from `$("input")` to `$(input)`.  See my edited answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the selector from `$("input")` to `$(input)`.  The former is the selector for ALL `<input>` elements... the latter is the selector using the `input` function argument that represents the *current* element being validated.

```
msg = $(input).prev("label").text();
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/n2cL6u7j/1/**

**NOTE**:  Remove the `click` handler and replace it with a DOM ready event handler.  The `.validate()` method is only used to initialize the plugin so it only needs to  get called once on DOM ready.  Otherwise, it gets called *once* when the form is loaded onto the page.  In your jsFiddle, you are calling `.validate()` every time the submit button of the form itself is clicked and this makes no sense.

---

---

**Original Answer:**  *(has some issues)*

Simply use the `errorPlacement` option to manipulate the message for the `required` rule as follows...

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if (error.text() === "required") { // <- only when the 'required' rule is used
        lbl = $(element).prev('label').text();
        error.text('Please fill out the ' + lbl + ' required field.');
    }
    error.insertAfter(element); // <- default placement
},
```

Since my conditional is looking at a "required" message for the `required` rule, I changed that message globally.  This was only done to simplify my conditional, and you could skip this entirely.

```
$.validator.messages.required = function (param, input) {
    return 'required';
}
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/jhdo83f8/

Comment: It is just returning 'required', your fiddle works though so its something I am screwing up.  However I can't fit the messages inline with the inputs, I need to place them in a separate div like I have above.

Comment: I appreciate the fix which was quite simple, usint $(input) vs $("input"). Also that is good advice on the click handler EXCEPT as I commented below the first time you brought that up, the form is brought in via AJAX so you have to bind it to the button click, it doesn't exist on DOM ready. Thanks though.

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign, as I tried to explain... how can it not yet exist when the click handler is bound to the submit button of the form itself?  The way your jsFiddle is constructed, you're calling `.validate()` every time the submit button is clicked!

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
$("input").each(function(i,op)
{
   alert($(this).prev("label").text());      
});
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.

Comment: Thats just a snipet how you can get the label text by iterating through each input control.

Comment: He does not need to iterate through anything.  He just needs the `label` for the field being validated.